# Bitbake: Appending with spaces combined with override syntax

Tags: bitbake

While reading some recipes I already stumbled multiple times upon this strange syntax:

From [linux-raspberripi.inc](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/meta-raspberrypi/tree/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-raspberrypi.inc)

```
# Add the kernel debugger over console kernel command line option if enabled
CMDLINE_append = ' ${@oe.utils.conditional("ENABLE_KGDB", "1", "kgdboc=serial0,115200", "", d)}'

# Disable rpi logo on boot
CMDLINE_append += ' ${@oe.utils.conditional("DISABLE_RPI_BOOT_LOGO", "1", "logo.nologo", "", d)}'
```

Is there any difference in what the second assignment does compared to the first one?

_append would require you to take care of the space, and += would do it for you. So, as there is already a space added to the string, wouldn't do = here exactly the same?

Also a funny find is the part in the [openembedded - Syntax of recipes](http://www.embeddedlinux.org.cn/OEManual/recipes_syntax.html) where they mention that (anti-?)style:

```
CFLAGS_prepend = "-I${S}/myincludes "
CFLAGS_prepend += "-I${S}/myincludes2 "
Note also the lack of a space when using += to append to a prepend value - remember that the += operator is adding space itself.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CMDLINE = "a"
CMDLINE_append = " b"
```

gives `CMDLINE = "a b"`

```
CMDLINE = "a"
CMDLINE_append += " b"
```

gives `CMDLINE = "a  b"`

so one will result in a double space, one will have a single space.